# Populating listview by AddRange

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

how can i populate an listview with an object by using Addrange. the object is:

```
 public class Cable : StateObject
   {       

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CablePropertyId { get; set; }
    public int Item { get; set; }
    public int TagNo { get; set; }
    public string GeneralFormat { get; set; }
    public string EndString { get; set; }
    public string CableRevision { get; set; }
    public string FromBay { get; set; }
    public string FromPanel { get; set; }     
}
```

Thanks

Comment: create an array of ListViewItem and add it to ur listview.

Answer (score 0):

Well, AddRange is defined on a List.

You could do something like :

```
var list_view = new ListView();
var some_array = new string[] {"1","2", "3", "4"};
var list_of_strings = new List<string>() ;
list_of_strings.AddRange(some_array);
list_view.ItemsSource = list_of_strings;
```

So, the add range accepts an IEnumerable.

In any point, the above example is a bit silly, since you since you could simply do this:

```
list_view.ItemsSource = some_array;
```

avoiding the need for the `list_of_strings` and the `AddRange`.